# How can I set up a pixel-perfect camera using OpenGL and orthographic projection?

Tags: opengl, 2d, textures, sprites

I am creating a 2D game using OpenGL and orthographic projection. For sprites, I use textured quads (actually two triangles).

I want the pixel art textures for the sprites to be displayed in a multiple of the original size to avoid blurry textures.

How can I set up a pixel-perfect camera using OpenGL and orthographic projection?
After doing so, how do I size the qauds?

Comment: How is your camera setup? Is it a pixel-perfect one? What is the viewport?

Comment: No, it is not. And now I also understand why the question was down voted. The question should actually be: how can I setup a pixel perfect camera using opengl and orthographic projection?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040961/opengl-pixel-perfect-2d-drawing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please take note that the question was unclear and changed meaning 3 times, hence the 3 answers in one**

### How can I verify that a given size is a multiple of another?

This is a very good case to use the Modulo operator.

Let's say you have a texture `tex` with size `(width, height)`. Now you want to render the texture with size `(drawWidth, drawHeight)` on the screen. You can verify that the draw size is a multiple of the original texture size using the following test:

```
if (drawWidth % tex.width == 0 && drawHeight % tex.height == 0
    && drawWidth != 0 && drawHeight != 0) {
    // Render the texture
}
```

*We need to test if `drawWidth` and `drawHeight` are not 0 because 0 modulo anything will return 0.*

The Modulo operator returns the remainder of an integer division. So let's say your texture is 64x64, like in your question,  and you want to render it with size 127x234:

```
64 % 127 = 63 (1 remainder 63) // This will fail the test
64 % 234 = 42 (3 remainder 42) // This will fail the test too
```

But using a multiple (for example, 128x192) gives the following result:

```
64 % 128 = 0 (2 remainder 0) // Pass
64 % 192 = 0 (3 remainder 0) // Pass
```

If you want to keep the ratio (always draw a square if the texture is a square, or always draw 2x3 if the texture has a ratio of 2x3), you can add the following to the condition:

```
if (drawWidth % tex.width == 0 && drawHeight % tex.height == 0
    && (drawWidth / tex.width) == (drawHeight / tex.height)
    && drawWidth != 0 && drawHeight != 0) {
    // Render the texture
}
```

This will test if the ratio is the same as the original image. The division will always return an integer value because both modulos returned 0.

### How can I render these sizes without them being blurry in my viewport?

**NOTE: This only needs to be applied if your camera viewport is not alreay pixel-perfect.**

Let's say you have a viewport with the following attributes:

```
screenWidth  // Width of the screen, in pixels
screenHeight // Height of the screen, in pixels
viewWidth    // Width of the OpenGL viewport
viewHeight   // Height of the OpenGL viewport
```

To render your texture with size `(drawWidth, drawHeight)`, you have to calculate the ratio of the pixels compared to the viewport:

```
ratioX = viewWidth / screenWidth;
ratioY = viewHeight / screenHeight;
```

`ratioX` and `ratioY` tells you how many units the viewport spans in 1 pixel. If your camera spans from -1 to 1 on the X axis (default OpenGL camera), and your screen width in pixels is 1024, then the ratio will be `2 / 1024 = 0.00195...`, which tells you that for each pixel on the screen, the OpenGL position increments by that amount.

You then need to multiply your `drawWidth` and `drawHeight` with those ratios:

```
drawWidth *= ratioX;
drawHeight *= ratioY;
```

This will give you pixel-perfect rendering of textures. If you want to take into account a texture position, you can multiply your `drawX` and `drawY` the same way to scale it.

### How can I setup a pixel-perfect camera then?

It is simple to setup a pixel-perfect orthographic projection. You only need to modify 2 matrices in OpenGL (legacy):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, screenWidth, 0, screenHeight, 1, -1); // Origin in lower-left corner
glOrtho(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, 1, -1); // Origin in upper-left corner
```

Comment: OK it seems I misstated the question, I am sorry. I want to know how much I have to scale the quads to get that certain pixel size. How can I improve the question?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Sorry for the confusion. And how to do it in modern OpenGL?

Comment: I do beleive it works the exact same way for modern (3+) OpenGL, but I've specified Legacy just in case it doesn't.